# Why didn't max dump the trailer of mother's milk?

Tags: mad-max-fury-road

For some bizzare reason Mad Max and the gang decide to lug what must be several thousand kg of mother's milk across hundreds of miles of desert. Why didn't they leave the trailer behind so that the cab of the rig could travel far, far faster using far less fuel? It actually makes no sense why they should keep it once Furiosa's cover's been blown. Maybe the fuel pod's hitch isn't compatible with the rig's so Furiosa couldn't trade the pod with the bikers, but they even stop after the canyon, and even then they decide on lugging this tanker. This tanker that enables countless assailants to actually land on it and attack the cab, now that I think of it. They couldn't even drink or trade it after a few days...milk in an unrefrigerated tank in the desert would go rancid in days.

It makes the scene where the V8 Interceptor and the rig are trying to get ahead of each other slightly ridiculous, even in the world of Mad Max.

[image: spit]
Instead of spluttering into an airscoop and blowing an engine, why not just unhook that 30,000kg of worthless milk you're lugging? (And it really is worthless at this point. Even if mother's milk is highly valuable, our heroes plan is to take over the citadel where the mothers themselves are actually housed.)

It's also definitely mother's milk inside the trailer. Not only is it stated by one of the wives before Max washes blood off his face with it, but you can see it during the final chase squirting out when the harpoons hit the tanker (can't find image online; sorry). If they were carrying fuel it would make more sense, as fuel doesn't go off and will always, always, always be the most valuable resource in the world of Mad Max. However, perishable milk? I doubt the salts in milk would make it as valuable as water in the desert anyway. Just don't git it.

Okay. I've just noticed that Nux' brother/lancer actually appears to be holding a bottle of milk in that pic. He was spitting mother's milk into the air intake this whole time?

Sorry, what? What even is mother's milk? Is it actually a mixture of fuel and milk? The warboyz scar themselves with the prints of V8 Engines as though they are both man and machine, and vice-versa. The rig has a human arm bone painted onto its door. They of course spray their lips and teeth shiny and chrome like the grill of a car. Is part of the warboyz' belief blurring the line between man and machine and is mixing mother's milk with fuel part of this?

Is mother's milk actually fuel, and is that why they didn't dump it?

Comment: Just a tip - this question is *really* long - you might want to condense it a bit ;)

Comment: @N_Soong that would make it...condensed milk.

Comment: He isn't holding a bottle of milk in the pic.  He's holding an ordinary squirt bottle, and he's using it to spray gasoline into the car.  It's pretty clear in the actual scene.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tanker doesn't just contain mother's milk (which is just breast milk). It also contains water. Aside from the obvious economic value of both commodities (and its utility for bargaining with), they're also valuable for basic survival.

What they refer to as guzzolene is the fuel (gasoline). And that's what was contained in the fuel pod.

However, the reason they didn't unhitch the tanker on the return trip was because their plan involved blocking the pass with it, thus stranding their pursuers long enough for them to take over the Citadel. It wouldn't have worked without the tanker.

Though I'm not sure how they expected to pull that off without a separate vehicle. Unhitching a semitrailer takes time. You have to be at a full stop and, at minimum, deploy a pair of trailer jacks (otherwise, the front half of the semitrailer is sitting on the tractor) and disengage the fifth wheel before you're able to drive out from under it.

Lastly, the way a semi-truck is geared, it was never going to outrun those other vehicles, with or without the tanker. At least with the tanker attached, you can sort of use it as a weapon.

Comment: Yea, they were going to trade the milk/water for safe passage, but I'd assumed they kept it after that fell through either because they didn't know how long it'd take them to find the green place (or if they'd even find it), so having a supply of food and water was vital, or just to be able to use it for trade in the future in case the opportunity arose.

Comment: Lèse majesté that does put my mind at rest, interesting that trucks have a set speed. Thinking about it, I'm sure the trailer could be disengaged from the cab while in motion, these are heavily, heavily, heavily modified vehicles. (Nux' car can go full speed in reverse gear ect)